# What caused and ended the time loop in Groundhog Day?

Tags: plot-explanation, time-travel, groundhog-day

I've always wondered what caused the Time Loop experienced by Phil Connors in Groundhog Day, as well as what ended it, but I don't recall it being discussed in the movie.

What was the cause for the time loop featured in Groundhog Day, and why did it end?

Comment: I remember seeing an interview, somewhere that I can't for the life of me find now, where it was said that what broke the spell was Bill Murray's kissing the hotel owner. Apparently "the music shimmers" right then, or something.

Comment: I am no expert on the subject, but it seems to me related to a belief in Buddhism that, according to the life you led, you will reincarnate into the exact same (horrible) living being if you behaved wrongly ; or evolve and become a superior being (if you were a good person), breaking the circle of reincarnations.

Comment: @wil where is that explained in the movie?

Comment: I may have seen the movie 20-odd times and still wouldn't know the answer to your question. Time and time again I marvel at what may be the reason the loop ends and find different answers each time. To me that's the true greatness of this movie: it's like a painting that's a bit different each time you see it and while you evolve and understand the world a little different, your conclusions on this movie evolveand change with you. And does the loop really end? Doesn't he wish to stay there for the rest of his life?

Comment: Don't know what caused it, but see https://www.overthinkingit.com/2014/06/05/groundhog-day-time-loop-parallel-universe/ for what ended it. It never did end!

Answer (score 167, accepted):

According to [this review](https://web.archive.org/web/20110624063754/http://creativejamie.com/2011/02/05/groundhog-day-movie-review/) answering such questions in the movie itself would have "ruined" it. The original script contained an explanation of the start of the time loop - a voodoo spell - but that was considered a poor idea.

So, I wonder if there is a conclusive answer to your question. It was deliberately left out by Harold Ramis. We are left speculating about it (maybe even encouraged to do so) and I think that is one of the reasons why this movie has had so much impact.

Comment: To me the loop symbolizes that for some people - like Phil - due to their closed-mindedness life is anyway pretty much a loop of making the same decisions and mistakes again and again - just that it usually isn't as obvious as in the movie. And the moment he truly changed something about his attitude to life and the people around him - he left the loop.

Answer (score 75):

I don't believe a formal answer was ever provided in the movie, but it seemed to require Phil to finally diverge from a path of pure selfishness and embrace the ideals of love and respect for other human beings. He started the movie disrespecting the cameraman Larry (Chris Elliott) and the producer Rita (Andi MacDowell) by blowing off the ceremony by being late, providing poor commentary, and acting generally boorish to everybody including town officials, the landlady, and former acquaintances like Ned. He needed to see his disrespect of them through many incarnations of the day and change his attitude. Only when his attitude was proved to be changed by his love of Rita, was he able to escape the time loop.

Comment: I felt there was an added element to it.  Phil started to help/think of other people before the loop ended (e.g. the old man he'd initially ignored, but then tried continually to save).  The crucial element was that he had to become such a good person that ***Rita could 'fall in love' with him in a single day***  I put 'fall in love' in inverted commas since she might just have been fond of him, but it seemed she was the crucial 'loop breaking' element.  +1 for the answer.

Comment: I can understand that opinion, that it was necessary for the rest of the people to value Phil, rather than just his changing, that helped break the cycle. Sort of a 'Pay it Forward' view.

Comment: @Andrew Rita falling in love with him itself is not the crucial element; it is evidence and metaphor of the crucial element: Phil becoming completely a 'good person'.

Comment: I agree that the crucial element was Phil changing. Rita falling in love was the proof of this change, not the cause of the end of the loop.

Answer (score 64):

It's a very very hidden big irony.

He started the movie as a jerk and egotist, with everything in his mind being about him and not caring about others. At least, on a minor, 1-person scale. We are led to believe that this perception of things being about him are wrong.

Then, as we find out after the movie ends (see [wbogacz](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/828/235)'s excellent answer), the whole **universe** was frozen in thousands of days of a loop, **all for the express purpose of providing a lesson to Phil that his initial worldview is wrong**.

Except, in the end, it **is** all about Phil. The only mistake in the beginning that he made was the scale - **the whole UNIVERSE is about him,** not just an individual personal bubble of things around him.

Comment: I guess he was right when he said, "I'm a god!"

Comment: Furthermore, if Phil had wanted to learn a new skill, make a pile of money by playing the day trading market, or allow himself more time to enjoy his vacation, he merely has to act selfishly for a day and the Universe permits the day to be repeated. His friends & loved ones won't remember what a jerk he was for that one day. :)

Answer (score 32):

If you take the movie as **allegory** this question — and the movie — become sublime.

While I like wbogacz's and DVK's answers very much, I humbly suggest they are incomplete.  It's about more than overcoming selfishness or solipsism (all about me) or even insufficient solipsism, as keen an insight as that is.  For me the answer to the original question comes when the movie is taken as allegorical, an analogy for one of life's deepest lessons.

**When today is invested in tomorrow, only that breaks the monotonous cycle of days.**

Yes selflessness is a part of that.  So is empathy as an antidote to solipsism.  But neither explain the piano lessons.  Those represent pure and simple investment today into a better tomorrow, and so form a part of the escape from each new day being no better — being indistinguishable — from the last.

I know little of Buddhism (and half of that from just now reading Wikipedia) but the lesson reminds me of the Buddhist concept of liberating oneself from the endless cycle of suffering and rebirth.  I wonder if reincarnation was originally an analogy for the same concept: to invest in today for a better tomorrow is to attain greatness.

Answer (score 28):

It was a miracle of God intervening in his life.

For whatever reason, he was permitted to experience reality over and over and over again, while fully cognizant and fully remembering everything prior.

It's like conscious reincarnation, each day being a new life, only with him starting out as a 45 yro instead of an infant.

After thousands of days, he had successfully traversed from

- infant - not knowing what the heck is going on,
- child - innocent child trying to figure things out,
- teenager - hedonistically having fun, robbing banks, dying, etc.,
- adult - trying to make things right, seeking Enlightenment (piano playing, learning foreign languages, etc.),
- wise sage - a state near enlightenment where only Today mattered and all his desires were overlooked for the benefit of others and the betterment of the world. Rita was a perk, not his sole mission.

In this sense, the movie is a clear indication of the cycle of Reincarnation, albeit one where this individual did not have to be reset continuously inorder to progress.

The ending is him literally breaking out of Maya (illusion), as the Hindus say, and leading a wholly Activated, Enlightened existence, without the need of further reincarnations.

Comment: nice itemized growth! +1 for wisdom and selflessness. God + hindu enlightenment ... Plothole?

Answer (score 21):

The [second draft](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/groundhogday.pdf) of the script states that Phil was cursed by his ex-girlfriend. After they trimmed her character from [later versions](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/Groundhog-Day.pdf) of the script (finally removing her entirely from the film), that plotline made no sense, so they seem to have decided to simply leave it as an un-resolved question:

> **CUT TO:**
>
> **INSERT : A THICK BOOK** The cover reads "101 Curses, Spells and
>   Enchantments You Can Do at Home." A well-manicured feminine hand opens
>   the book to a marked page .
>
> **INT. CHERRY STREET INN - NIGHT - SAME TIME :** Phil enters his room and
>   drunkenly tosses his overcoat, scarf and gloves on the floor in a
>   heap.
>
> **INT. STEPHANIE'S BEDROOM - NIGHT :** Stephanie Decastro, Phil ' s
>   disaffected ex-lover, is sitting cross-legged on the floor with the
>   book of curses open in front of her. Her hair is down, she's wearing a
>   caftan with a Zodiac print, there are candles everywhere and other
>   vaguely occult decorating touches.
>
> **INSERT :** Phil's business card is dropped into a dish. Then the Tarot
>   card of the Hanged Man, a chicken bone, and a feather are placed on
>   top of it .
>
> **PHIL :** He stands at the sink, looking at himself in the mirror, flexing
>   his muscles.
>
> **STEPHANIE :** Reading from the book she mutters incantations in a secret
>   language, then she sprinkles some powder on the plate, then a few
>   drops of oil. Then she makes a few passes over it with her hands and,
>   much to her surprise, the contents of the plate spontaneously combust.
>
> **PHIL :** As he crosses to the bed, he accidentally knocks over the
>   suitcase stand, spilling his clothes out onto the floor.-25- He
>   contemplates picking them up for a moment, decides to leave them
>   there, and flops down on the bed. He lies there looking up at the
>   ceiling until the room starts to spin around, then he closes his eyes
>   and quickly drops off to sleep, still fully clothed.
>
> **STEPHANIE :** To complete the spell, she picks up a broken wristwatch and
>   drops it into the fire.
>
> **INSERT :** Phil's business card, the Hanged Man and the broken watch in
>   flames. The watch crystal is cracked and the hands are frozen at 5:59

It is also worth noting that in the earlier draft, the original spell kept Phil in the loop for 10,000 years(ish) and that it was Rita's kiss that finally broke the curse;

> **Phil :** *You want to know what's really amazing? I've been waiting for you every day for ten thousand years. I dream of you every night
>   of my life. You've been my constant weapon against total despair, and
>   just knowing you exist has kept me alive. How's that?*

Comment: I'm glad they omitted such corny and cliché ingredients.

Comment: A thousand years might be an exaggeration though, just meaning he has waited a very long time.

Answer (score 12):

The first lines of the movie:

> "Somebody asked me today...
>   *"Phil, if you could be anywhere, where would you like to be?"*
>
> I said to him,
>   *"Probably right here."*
>
> Elko, Nevada."

In screenwriting, many devices are used to give us a clue of what the movie is about. Not what happens, but what it is about. For example, it could be said that many movies announce the premise of the story in the first scene. In this case, I think that this is more than a movie where the time repeats itself, its a movie about a selfish guy who has to learn to be open to the (sometimes chaotic) experience of living, and really share with other people. Many forms of belief (spiritual, most of all) would call this **Be present in the moment: Be here**. As Bill Murray says at the beginning... **I said to him,
*"Probably right here."***

So, the only way to get to this point of maturity is making mistakes over and over. Is a way of saying "you will make the same mistakes, over and over, until you learn the lesson about yourself and life".

Comment: HONEST AND HUMBLE LOVE BROKE THE SPELL

Answer (score 12):

I think many are missing this crucial dialogue in the movie:

> **Rita:** I don't know what to say.
>
> **Phil:** I do. No matter what happens tomorrow, or for the rest of my life, I'm happy now.

The loop broke when it was pointless to continue further: I think this is crucial. Each day before that one had the potential to be different, to be better; but not the one when he says that dialogue - it was already as good as we could hope for. Phil explicitly admits this, and the spell's broken.

I know of others' points that Rita was at the centre of it all, but I don't think she was *that* crucial, I'd rather say it had more to do with the groundhog and its shadow; the last day was the one that Phil didn't see his shadow.

Comment: this should be the answer