# How many times did Satoru relive his childhood in Erased?

Tags: plot-explanation, erased

In the final episode of the ***Erased***, (originally known as ***Boku dake ga Inai Machi*** or *The Town Without Me*), it is revealed that the main character Satoru has relived his childhood multiple times in the course of the show before it's final episode.

In the vain the infamous "[How long was Groundhog's Day](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44307/48480)" question, how many times has Satoru relived his childhood?

Comment: While to an extent he can relive the same period multiple times, he is limited to two rewinds. After doing so failing his first he mentions that this second would be the last chance. Why this is is never really explained.

Comment: @krazer Would you like to post this as an answer?